# Take advantage of - positively

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, synonyms, connotation

The phrase "take advantage of" is usually perceived as negative. Is there a word or a phrase with a similar meaning which would convey a more positive meaning? Akin to "make use of the situation" but more refined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Opportunity**](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/opportunity)

"Games and songs provide the *perfect opportunity* for classroom interaction and language development."

and also **Golden opportunity** - *a very good chance to do or achieve something*

Answer (score 3):

You can try ***harness***

> : utilize

Or change the sentence structure where you can use the word "leverage"

Answer (score 2):

To say "take advantage of someone" definitely has a negative connotation, but not necessarily so when you say "take advantage of an opportunity".  Even to say "to take advantage of someone's knowledge" isn't necessarily negative.

Comment: The context is very sensitive, as the same party that's taking advantage of the situation can be regarded as either good or bad.

Answer (score 2):

A positive use:-  I'm going to sit in my garden and *take advantage of* this glorious weather

Answer (score 1):

A verb that is widely used in Irish English (but in Britain sounds slightly old-fashioned) is

> to avail of

For example, you can avail of a special offer, or avail of someone's generosity.

I do not know if this is used in the US.

Comment: The grammatically correct usage is "to avail oneself of"

Comment: @moonstar2001, the elliptical ‘avail of’ is not grammatically incorrect as such, it is just rarer and more old-fashioned (except in Ireland). Especially Shakespeare was fond of the elliptical construction; and when used in the passive, only the elliptical version is found: “Power must be availed of” (Emerson, _Conduct of Life_).

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing a paper and need a way of saying 'to take advantage of' an opportunity in a way that is neutral and can be used by either a profit or nonprofit firm that perceives an opportunity to satisfy a human need. The closest word I have found is **'seize' an opportunity**. This term is used in a framework for Dynamic Capabilities described by David Teece in 2007.